# Best format for saving list of JSON strings

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to run an ETL over a lot of XML files that exist in my datalake. The first step is to translate those XML files into JSON files because it way easier to load JSON files into databases rather than XML strings.

I'm trying to understand what format is better :

Format 1

```
[{'key':val}, {'key':val}, {'key':val}, {'key':val}]
```

Format 2:

```
{'key':val}, {'key':val}, {'key':val}, {'key':val}
```

Format 3 (as one column CSV):

```
{'key':val}
{'key':val}
{'key':val}
```

The advantage of file 1 is that I'm able to load that file back with json.load which I can't do to the second example (I'll get `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data:` ) .

The advantage of file2 is that I can load that file as it is to many databases.

Another option is saving all 3 versions of the file but feels like a waste of space if there is any other good solution.

Comment: I'm not sure I see the advantage of `XML -> JSON -> Database` vs just doing `XML -> Database`, since it seems like most of the work is that initial conversion from XML to Python data structures. Both formats 1 and 3 are very easy to read in with Python. Pick whichever makes your work easiest.

Comment: the XML is raw data, it needs some preprocessing before going onwards into db. I need to parse the xml.. Therefore, I decided to convert it to json because it much more human readable and much more easier to work with.